Update or replace a list of child entities in a @OneToMany relation
Given two simple entities Parent and Child with a OneToMany relationship. I have written a helper method for replacing the list of children with a new list. However, I'm not sure if this is a propery way to update the list of children.
Would it be better to distinguish between:

Child elements, which do not exist yet, are added
Child elements, which do exist, are updated
Child elements, which do not exist anyore, are removed

@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void replaceChildren(List<Child> newChildren) {
        this.children.clear();
        newChildren.forEach(this::addChild);
    }

    private void addChild(Child child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

}


Seems fine because of orphan removal which will delete any unreferenced child objects. Otherwise, the ones not in the list would need to be modified to point at a different parent (or null). I presume you call merge after you call replaceChildren to ensure that any changes in child instances are picked up - JPA will detect new objects but may not handle detached objects in the collection well without the explicit merge call.
